# Automated use of PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Is there a way I can sensibly automate the PlotLegends expressions within plot so as to correctly label each curve even when I change some of the initial parameter values? For example, consider the plot

```
a = 1;
b = 3;
c = 1;
ListPlot[Table[Table[{n, m n^2}, {n, 1, 5}], {m, a, b, c}], 
 Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"m=1", "m=2", "m=3"}]
```

I've got the values in the PlotLegends expressions specific to the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ I've used initially. Is there a way to generate a table (for example) for PlotLegends along the lines of

```
a = 1;
b = 3;
c = 1;
ListPlot[Table[Table[{n, m n^2}, {n, 1, 5}], {m, a, b, c}], 
 Joined -> True, PlotLegends ->Table[{"a+(n-1)c"},{n,1,(b-a)/c+1}]]
```

This itself doesn't work but I'd imagine something similar might?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, the simplest way is pre-defining the list of names for legend entries. Let's say, like this:

```
 lbls = Table["m=" <> ToString[m], {m, {1, 2, 3}}];

 ListPlot[Table[{n, m n^2}, {m, {1, 2, 3}}, {n, 1, 5}], 
          Joined -> True,
          PlotLegends -> lbls]
```

Actually, any feature of PlotLegend can be pre-defined (styling labels, frame style, etc).

Answer (score 6):

I think the easiest way is to use the fact that most plotting functions use association keys as legend entries when you give them the data in the form `<|"key1"->data1,...|>`:

```
a = 1; b = 3; c = 1;
ListPlot[
 <|
  Table[
   StringTemplate["m=``"][m] ->
    Table[{n, m n^2}, {n, 1, 5}],
   {m, a, b, c}
   ]
  |>,
 Joined -> True
 ]
```

[image]

Note also the use of [`StringTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html) to build the key/legend entry. This also has the advantage that you keep the data and labels together. (since you don't need to take care that the list of legend entries is the same length and in the same order as the data)

Answer (score 4):

Nested `Table`s can be coded with a single `Table`.

```
a = 1;
b = 3;
c = 1;
nmax = 5;

ListLinePlot[
 Table[m n^2, {m, b, a, -c}, {n, nmax}],
 PlotLegends ->
  (StringForm["m=``", #] & /@ Range[b, a, -c]), 
 PlotRange -> {{1, nmax}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Or using [`PlotLabels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabels.html)

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[m n^2, {m, a, b, c}, {n, nmax}],
 PlotLabels ->
  (StringForm["m=``", #] & /@ Range[a, b, c]), 
 PlotRange -> {{1, nmax}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
a = 1; b = 3; c = 1;
data = Table[Table[{n, m n^2}, {n, 1, 5}], {m, a, b, c}];
```

Recently bumped into a built-in function `PromptForm` that can be used for the current task:

```
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> (PromptForm["m", #] & /@ Range[3])]
```

[image]

Using Lukas Lang's method with `PromptForm`:

```
ListPlot[AssociationThread[PromptForm["m", #] & /@ Range[3], data], Joined -> True]
```

[image]